# How do you change an outside variable inside a function passing a parameter Noobie in swift

Tags: swift, function, variables, parameters, call

How do you change an outside variable inside a function with passing a parameter?; Noobie in swift

```
var varIsTrue:Bool = true

import UIKit
extension UIDevice {

class ViewController: UIViewController {
 override func viewDidLoad() {

  changeVar(varIsTrue , false)
     
 }

 func changeVar(_ varName:? , _ arg:Bool){
         varName = arg // Xcode cannot assign to value: 'varName' is a 'let' constant

             }
// varName:? Don't know if the question mark should be a :String some kind of argument or what?
           }
      }
```

Comment: What's wrong with `varIsTrue = false`?

Comment: You can use inout

Comment: @George_E varITrue = false wont pass the reference  to be change it will get the param that is on the function.. as aheze  mention inout is the the way 2 pass the reference see Alex  Goersin he's example was well explained  thank you  Alex Goersin

Comment: @dinolin I meant to use it instead of `changeVar(varIsTrue, false)`. The answer given is the same functionality of `varIsTrue = false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your example is just an abstraction and you're trying to understand the concept of changing a variable from within a function this would be a solution.

Like already mentioned in the comments you need to use `inout` and pass the reference (indicated by the leading `&`) of your "outside variable".

```
var varIsTrue: Bool = true

changeVar(&varIsTrue , false)

func changeVar(_ property: inout Bool , _ arg: Bool){
    property = arg
}
```

Comment: Well explained example !